# Paypal sandbox endpoint webservice - Error "You do not have permissions to make this API call"

Tags: authentication, soap, permissions, paypal, sandbox

I used this paypal endpoint webservice for my PHP5 SoapClient :

```
Sandbox API Signature   SOAP    https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/
```

And when i send my soap request with my credentials, i get an error with :

- Ack => failure
- ErrorCode => 10002
- Short message => Authentication/Authorization failed
- Long message => You do not have permissions to make this API call

This is current Soap message send to soap paypal API :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" 
xmlns:ns2="ebl:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ns3="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" 
xmlns:ns4="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">

<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns3:RequesterCredentials xsi:type="ns4:UserIdPasswordType">
        <Username>xxxxx</Username>
        <Password>xxxxx</Password>
        <Signature>xxxxx</Signature>
    </ns3:RequesterCredentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>

<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns3:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
    <ns3:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>

      <ns1:Version>84.0</ns1:Version>

              <ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails 
               xsi:type="ns2:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType">

               <ReturnUrl>url_to_/success.paypal.php</ReturnUrl>
               <CancelUrl>url_to_/cancel.paypal.php</CancelUrl>
               <LocaleCode>US</LocaleCode>

              </ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>

    </ns3:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
    </ns3:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I instantiated this PHP5 SoapClient :

```
//Endpoint
$location = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/';
$uri = 'urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI';

//SoapClient options
$options = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 'location'=>$location, 'uri'=>$uri);

//My Soap Client
$client =new SoapClient('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl',$options);
```

But when I called SetExpressCheckout paypal soap service, i receive the following soap message :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" 
xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" 
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" 
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" 
xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" 
xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" 
xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">

<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"
                      xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security>

    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"
                                  xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">

        <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
                                 xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
                    </Credentials>
    </RequesterCredentials>

</SOAP-ENV:Header>

<SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">

    <SetExpressCheckoutResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">

       <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
               2012-01-13T12:09:01Z
           </Timestamp>

    <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Failure</Ack>
    <CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
                c8d551f118a1
            </CorrelationID>

    <Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:ErrorType">

           <ShortMessage xsi:type="xs:string">
                           Authentication/Authorization Failed
                   </ShortMessage>

           <LongMessage xsi:type="xs:string">
                        You do not have permissions to make this API call
                   </LongMessage>

            <ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:token">10002</ErrorCode>
            <SeverityCode xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
                          Error
                        </SeverityCode>
        </Errors>

        <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">84.0</Version>
        <Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2271164</Build>

    </SetExpressCheckoutResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Nevertheless, I used the API credentials of my business account test...
I don't understand why my code doesnt work.

The error is : 'You do not have permissions to make this API call', but how it's possible? Because i use the correct endpoint service (sandbox) ?

Comment: The messages seem pretty obvious... you're either not including the correct credentials, or you're not allowed to do whatever your API request wants to do. Without showing any code, that's the best answer you'll get.

Comment: My post is very short and simple because i did not have answer for the real post. Just go to get a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850959/php-soapclient-for-paypal-setexpresscheckout-authentication-failure

Comment: Then you should have posted the code here, and not started a separate question.

Comment: @blue_diamond i have same problem but i am not getting solution.Can you tell me solution how you solved problem, i am tried lot.Reply plz.

Comment: @Aniket sorry to late only now, but i dont have anymore this code. If my memories are good, you just have to put credentials elements in a <Credentials></Credentials> element. 
Here is a sample of the XSD file used by Paypal API : 
`<element name="Credentials" type="ns:UserIdPasswordType" minOccurs="0"/>
<complexType name="UserIdPasswordType">
  <sequence>
  ...
  <element name="Username" type="xs:string" />
  <element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
  <element name="Signature" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  ...
  </sequence>
<complexType/>`